# Why was my flag to a seemingly non-constructive comment declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Three days ago I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732996/how-can-i-convert-utf-8-to-ansi-in-python#comment20613234_14732996) as not constructive. The content of the comment is:

> `sudo python convert_files_to_ansi.py`?

For reference, the title and body of the question are the following:

> ### How can I convert UTF-8 to ANSI in Python
>
> I have text files in UTF-8. I want to convert that files to ANSI.

However, the flag was declined.

I'm not quite sure why the flag was declined, but I can think of a few possible explanations:

- An accident. A moderator agreed with me, but accidentally declined the flag.
- According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198005/176436):

  > Some moderators don't delete comments unless they are actively harmful. It takes less time to dismiss a comment flag than it does to delete it; some comments require opening the post to see the context of the comment before deleting it (especially the Obsolete ones).

  The comment is most likely not actively harmful, so the flag might have been dismissed.
- Without context, one might think that the comment *is* constructive. After all, the comment consists of a valid Linux command and a question mark, indicating a genuine suggestion to the OP.

What could the reason be? Why was the flag declined?

Comment: Why do you think that comment is not constructive?  I personally don't see anything wrong with the comment.  I also don't see why it would need to be deleted.

Comment: Don't expect moderators to make the call on technical matters.  They don't realize it was a joke.

Comment: While I don't think the comment provides enough value to be kept, I don't really see the purpose of flagging comments on a closed question. The question should be removed entirely, not just the comments on it.

Comment: A year old, -7 score question and your bone to pick is over a flagged comment? Priorities, yo.

Comment: @bluefeet: [context for the joke](http://xkcd.com/149/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never would have gotten that :)

Comment: Because, Blue line

Comment: @MartijnPieters I doubt that there was any connection with the XKCD cartoon — the use of `sudo` is as nonsensical as the rest of the comment (which uses a file name that nobody else has used on the web).

Comment: @Gilles: the joke is pretty lame, but I am 95% certain the joker referred to that XKCD comic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When moderators are reviewing comments we can Delete or Dismiss

- Delete - marks the flag as helpful
- Dismiss - declines the comment flag

I was the moderator who reviewed the flag, I don't recall if I opened the full question when reviewing it but it didn't seem like it needed to be deleted so I dismissed your flag. We typically don't delete comments unless it is necessary, I didn't see any harm in leaving this comment.  I wouldn't worry too much about a declined comment flag.

Now that it's been pointed out that this is a joke comment, it's been deleted.

Comment: In context, it's very obviously a troll: the file name `convert_files_to_ansi.py` doesn't appear anywhere on the Internet other than in that comments and quotes of it, and the use of `sudo` is patently ridiculous.

Comment: @Gilles As I said, I don't recall if I opened the full question to review it.  Based on the comment alone, I didn't see anything wrong with it, which is why I dismissed it.